# Including pages from database

Tags: php, mysqli, include

i am trying to include all my pages' contents in one page. With each pages' content being inside a div. How do i make my database include all the pages' content? Some pages has photographs, api, etc.

subject database

id  menu_name   position    visible
1   Website_Pages   1           1
2   Database    2           0

Pages Database

id  subject_id  menu_name   position    visible
1   1   template2           1           1
2   1   template_replace_oo 2           1
3   1   photo_gallery           3           1

index.php

```
<div id ="main">
        <?php 

        $query = "SELECT * ";
        $query .= "FROM subjects ";
        $query .= "WHERE id = 1 ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($result);

        while($subject = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        ?>



        <?php

        $query = "SELECT content ";
        $query .= "FROM pages ";
        $query .= "WHERE visible = 1 ";
        $query .= "AND subject_id = 1 ";
        $query .= "ORDER BY position ASC";
        $page_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($page_set);

       $output = "<div>";


       while($page = mysqli_fetch_assoc($page_set)) {

          $output .=  include($page['menu_name']."php");

            $output .= "</div>";
  // INDEX PAGE IS FOR PUBLIC DISPLAY !  
   // parse the navigation section that i sent into functions.php
   return $output;
       }
        }
   ?>
```

Comment: Y'our closing your while bracket too late, you should close it before `$output .= "</div>";`. Do you store html inside your database ?

Comment: Thanks that finally got it to at least display the contents inside. 

erm my database doesnt store them inside and most of the pages are php. Would it be better to store the php inside the database? And if so, how do i go about doing it? Sorry im kind of new to this

Comment: No, do not store php in database...even storing html inside a database is not good practice.